# less mixin for looping over a list without using extract and length functions, less version 1.3.3

Tags: css, list, loops, less

I have been trying to loop over a list and generate some css, however i am stuck with version 1.3.3 which doesn't have "extract" and "length" methods. Also the less compiler in use doesn't support javascript, so 'backtick' is also not working.

To give an example

// The list of strings

```
@items: ~"#item1", ~"#item2", ~"#item3"

.desired-mixin(@parent-name, @items ) {
  @{parent-name}{
    .some-class {
       @{current_item} { display: block }
     }
  }
}

.desired-mixin(~".parent-name", @items);
```

// Generated css

```
.parent-name .some-class #item1 { display: block; } 
.parent-name .some-class #item2 { display: block; }
.parent-name .some-class #item3 { display: block; }
```

Some pointers on this would be great, let me know if additional details are required.

Comment: The question is do you actually need these items to be in a list variable? Why do you need such mixins at all? Why can't you write what you need just [like this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.parent-name%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.some-class%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23item1%2C%20%23item2%2C%20%23item3%20%7B%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20block%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D)? Obviously, if there's no `extract` you can't do anything with such list variable.

Comment: Alternatively you can always use a real selector list instead of the variable and won't need any loop...

Comment: Something [like this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%2F%2F%20usage%5Cn%5Cn.list(items)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%23item1%2C%20%23item2%2C%20%23item3%20%7B.-%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.parent-name%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20.desired-mixin(items)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20impl.%5Cn%5Cn.desired-mixin(%40list)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.some-class%20%7B.list(%40list)%7D%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20.-()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20block%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D) (exact code may vary depending on your actual needs).

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks, i just wanted to check if there's a workaround for the "extract" limitation, the other two solutions are reasonably good.

Comment: Also, ".-" is a new operator for me, can you share some link where i can read about it ?

Comment: `.-` is not an operator, it's a regular mixin name (you can use `.whatever` instead).